# Comparing Numerical Precision in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have the following dataset:

```
number_1    number_2    number_3    number_1    number_2    number_3
0.36        0.36        0.3408      0.00036000  0.00036000  0.00034080
0.36        0.36        0.3408      0.00036000  0.00036000  0.00034080
0.36        0.36        0.3408      0.00036000  0.00036000  0.00034080
0.36        0.36        0.3408      0.00036000  0.00036000  0.00034080
```

What SQL function or query can I use that compares the numerical precision of both (assuming both are numerical(15,8) datatype).

Basically what I want is a way of proving the first number_1 column is off by three zeros compared to the number_1 that begins with three zeros.

Comment: Why do you have two columns named `number_1` ?

Comment: they are from two different tables using an inner join

Comment: Why you cannot do this: `number_1 * 1000`?